# How do I call both this and base constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

How can I call this and base constructor? Is it possible to call?

Code I want to make is this

```
public class ObservableTestCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public T Parent;   
    public ObservableTestCollection(T parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }
    public ObservableTestCollection(T parent, IEnumerable<T> source): base(source) ,this(parent)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I call this and base constructor? Is it possible to call?

You cannot call this and base constructor like in your example.

To achieve what you are trying to do in your example, you are going to have to refactor it like this.

```
public class ObservableTestCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> {
    public T Parent;   

    //This constructor calls the instance constructor
    public ObservableTestCollection(T parent) : this(parent, Enumerable.Empty<T>()) {

    }

    //Instance constructor is calling the base constructor
    public ObservableTestCollection(T parent, IEnumerable<T> source) : base(source) {
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

The second constructor is used to populate local variable and call the base constructor. Lets call that constructor the *instance constructor*. The instance constructor is now available to be called by other constructors using the `this` keyword.

**[Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)**

> A constructor can invoke another constructor in the same object by
>   using the *this* keyword. Like *base*, *this* can be used with or without
>   parameters, and any parameters in the constructor are available as
>   parameters to this, or as part of an expression.

Comment: Would be better to have these the other way around, no?

Comment: Thanks. That's the way around and I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Language will not allow this. You need extract common code from both constructors to method, and call it from both constructors. This way your code will not be doublicated.